# How to refresh the page with an audio tag based on browser after click of hyperlink

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, html

I have a requirement where one can see an image or play an audio (CAPTCHA).I added the div tag around the image and audio and with click of hyperlink they do change the display of the div but the changes (div) get lost when page gets redisplayed.

Technology used: Java, JSP, javascript

There is a

1. section in the jsp which needs to
    a) display an image(default)    or

   b) play an audio when requested

   The "src" for both image and audio is a servlet.

   ```
   <tr> 
      <td> &nbsp;</td>
      <td> <div id="audioPlayerContainer" style="display:none"> </div> 
      </td>    
   </tr> 
   <tr>    
      <td> &nbsp;</td>
      <td><div id="imageContainer"> 
          <img src='MyServlet?mode=image&ts=<%=Math.random()%>' width="100" height="100"/>
       </div>  
      </td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. section in the jsp where links to alternate between requesting image or audio are present

   ```
   <a href="#" onclick="switchMode('audio');">Play audio</a> //       OR
   <a href="#" onclick="switchMode('image');> Show image</a>
   ```
3. javascript on click of link

   ```
   function switchMode(modeType){ 
     if (modeType=="audio"){       
         var uri = '/MyServlet?mode=audio&ts='+new Date().getTime();
         document.getElementById('audioPlayerContainer').style.display ="block";   
         document.getElementById('imageContainer').style.display ="none";
          //logic to determine the browser type and browser verion- embed tag or audio
        document.getElementById("audioPlayerContainer").innerHTML=
         "<embed src='"+uri+"' autostart='true' loop='false' height='100' width='100'/>";      
     }else if (modeType=="image"){ 
         document.getElementById("audioPlayerContainer").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('imageContainer').style.display ="block";
     }
    //page to reload with updated divs
    //window.location.href=window.location.href; 
    //window.location.reload(0); //Both reloads page, state of div tags comes bck to default
     //document.forms[0].submit();//this doesnt even seem to work 
   }
   ```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing/submitting/anything that navigates away from the page will not keep any changes you made since you are simply changing the dom element after the page has loaded; you are not "saving" this change anywhere. So maybe something like this?

```
<a href="#" onclick="?mode=audio">Play audio</a> //       OR
<a href="#" onclick="?mode=image"> Show image</a>
```

And then in your javascript do

```
modeType="<%= request.getParameter("mode") %>";
switchMode(modeType);
function SwitchMode(modeType){ //...
```

Also I don't understand why you need a refresh, it seems like the dom injection you are doing is already accomplishing what you want. please provide more detail if my solution does not solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks!!It worked. The issue was servlet was not being called because of missing context root. Once I added the context root in the src in javascript, I could see the audio player.